# VBA code is not displayed in MS Access (2016) - module not found error

Tags: vba, ms-access, office365, ms-access-2010, ms-office

I have an Access db which works with no issues.
When i transfer that file to my pc so that i can modify it and open the db, it corrupts.
More specific I get an “module not found ” error message, and when I try to view the VBA code I get those empty windows as shown on picture.
Then, if I move the file back to the original pc (where it was working correct) I get the same issue. That means that somehow my pc causes some damage on file?
I fully uninstalled the MS office package using the official support tool.
I reinstalled everything back, also the database engine but problem remains.
Any suggestions?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used a pc "registry cleaner tool" and problem solved.